# How can I make it so that this console.log is executed after the function above it has completed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase and I have run into an issue. What I am trying to do is allow a user to sign up, but to check the account doesn't already exist, I want to retrieve all of the usernames from firestore and then search through them to see if their proposed username already exists. Here is my code to do this:

```
document.querySelector("#form1").addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var users;
    firestore.collection("users").get().then(querySnapshot => {
        users = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        console.log(users);
    });
    console.log(users);
});
```

So I know that when I try to do console.log(users) for the second time, the function above may not have completed its execution which is why when I log it to the console I see "undefined". How can I change my code so that the second console.log(users) waits for the function above to complete?

I tried looking into this and found some stuff to do with "async" and "wait" but I couldn't figure out how to make these work in my code. Maybe that could be the solution?

Comment: Why do you need the second `console.log()`? You already printed the result in the first one.

Comment: both just for debugging, the first console.log() prints but the second doesn't

Comment: That's expected for exactly the reason you said in the question: it runs before the query finishes.

Comment: yep thanks my issue is solved now from the answer below, however if youre still around I do have on small question: as you can see in the answer below there is the code 
```var query = await ref.where("username", "==", theEnteredUsername).get();```
now what if I didnt want to store the result, how could I do something like:
```await ref.where("username", "==", theEnteredUsername).get();```

Comment: If you don't want to store the result there's no reason to wait for it.

Comment: I actually have a case where I don't want to store but do want to wait. So the situation is a sign up form where I make an asynchronous function call which checks whether the proposed username already exists and if so displays an error message. I need to wait for this call to finish before adding the new user to firestore or else when the asynchronous function completes, it will see the user that has just been added as already existing, and then display the error. This was happening so currently I have just left it as I did in the comment above but idk if there's a neater way.

Comment: You can call `await` without assigning to a variable. Just like calling an ordinary function if you don't care about the result.

Comment: oh wow I should have guessed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't warn you enough to not get all `users` to check if one of them has the same username. I can strongly recommend to query for a single user with the same username:

```js
document.querySelector("#form1").addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const theEnteredUsername = ""; // get it from somewhere

  // Create a reference to the cities collection
  var ref = firestore.collection("users");

  // Create a query against the collection.
  var query = await ref.where("username", "==", theEnteredUsername).get();

  if (query.empty) {
    //you can use the username
  } else {
    //username taken!!!
  }
});
```

Othervise your Firebase bill would be grow extremely with the increase of users in your app.

Comment: hi, thanks for the advice, I will use a query instead, but just so I can know, can you explain what the purpose of async is in the above code?

Comment: In order to use the `await` in your code the `function` or code block where you want to use it needs to have the `async`. That way other code that calls that `functions` knows that it's a asynchornous function.